# wprintf with UNICODE (Hebrew) characters

Tags: c, windows, unicode, console, hebrew

I have a wchar_t array with English and Hebrew characters and when I print it with wprintf() it prints to console the English characters only. When I'm using _wsetlocale( LC_ALL, L"Hebrew" ) I get the Hebrew characters as "????".
The machine I'm working on supports Hebrew of course.

BTW - using c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe and 'dir' on a directory with Hebrew characters, also shows "???" instead of Hebrew.

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: output contents of a Unicode file to console in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909187/c-output-contents-of-a-unicode-file-to-console-in-windows)

Answer (score 2):

Have you confirmed that your console font can handle unicode characters?  Most don't.  You might try the Consolas font.

When I've run into this before, I've found [this](http://www.siao2.com/2010/04/07/9989346.aspx) article by Michael Kaplan to be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Basically Microsoft's C runtime library isn't implemented very well to allow this.

You can do `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);` and then writing with wcout or wprintf will work. However trying to use cout or printf, or anything that doesn't write UTF-16 will then cause the program to crash.