# Cannot wcout wide string other than English

Tags: c++, windows, std

Trying to print wide strings on the console, but it seems that only first line of English characters are print out correctly. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::wcout << L"Hello" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"река" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"河流" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"川" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"река" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Hello" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the console output:

[image]

What's even weirder is that it seems it has swallowed all the characters after "peka", and not printing the last "Hello" either.

---

Edit:

Tried the suggested answer on this SO: [C++: output contents of a Unicode file to console in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909187/c-output-contents-of-a-unicode-file-to-console-in-windows)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    std::wcout << L"Hello" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"река" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"河流" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"川" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"река" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Hello" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Kind of solved part of the problem, but what happens to Chinese and Japanese in the middle?

[image]

Comment: It's not english, its `utf-8`. You have to set your encoding to `utf-16` instead.

Comment: I don't know how to print Chinese font. My Win10 console window is using "Consolas" which should show Chinese, but it doesn't. I think I marked this as duplicate too quickly.

Comment: I tried typing Asian alphabets directly in console window and powershell, but it could not display the names properly. It seems console window works for European alphabets, but not Asian alphabets, including Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Indian. Maybe the system requires special setup for those languages...

Comment: Neither Consolas nor Lucida Console support Chinese characters.