# Problem printing spanish (or italian) accents and ñ

Tags: c++, unicode, ascii, iostream

i'm having a problem when i read a file that has special characters in it, like á ó ñ ü è, and then printing them in the command prompt.

in the example below, the file read has "normal characters á é í ó ú ñ" saved in it, but one output is: "normal characters ├í ├® ├¡ ├│ ├║ ├▒"
and the other one: "Ø#".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    //setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Spanish");
        //wofstream file_write;
    
    wifstream file_read;
    
    wstring aux;    
    
    file_read.open("general\\read_file.txt");
    
    
    if(file_read.fail()){
        printf("Fail\n");
    }
    
    else{
        
        getline(file_read, aux);
        
        wcout << aux << endl;
        
        wprintf(L"%ls\n", aux);
        
    }
    
    file_read.close();
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see i tried using wcout, wfstreams, wprintf, and the setLocale function but none of those worked, what can causing the problem? For context my OS is windows 11

Comment: When asking questions containing code, the very first tag you should add is for the language in which you're coding, so that it's clear what you're asking about and to get it to the attention of people who may be able to help you. Also, you'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend the time to take the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of internationalization in C++. The first question you need to answer, yourself, is what encoding your file uses. This is something that you will need to figure out yourself, noone else on Stackoverflow can inspect this file in your computer and determine what encoding it uses. Is it UTF-8? UTF-16? Is it one of the windows character sets? What is it? Only when you figure that out, then it is possible to proceed to the next step. Good luck!

Comment: "The to_hstring function takes a std::string_view of UTF-8 code units and converts them to a UTF-16 string, represented as a winrt::hstring"
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210922-00/?p=105717

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it is only wonderful if you are on Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying extended ASCII characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882031/displaying-extended-ascii-characters)

Answer (score 3):

Wide streams are almost never a good choice for I/O because they treat the input as a sequence of `wchar_t` while nowadays files are usually stored in UTF-8. So the best way to fix it is to convert your file from whatever encoding it is in to UTF-8 and use narrow streams for I/O. For input you can continue using `getline` but output is a bit harder. In C++23 you'll be able to use [`std::print`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print) that correctly handles Unicode on various operating systems including Windows. In the meantime you could use [the open-source {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), `std::print` is based on. For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
  std::ifstream file_read("read_file.txt");
  std::string s;
  std::getline(file_read, s);
  fmt::print("{}\n", s);
}
```

If you use MSVC you should compile with `/utf-8` and, provided that your file is UTF-8, you should get the correct output.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 `std::format`.

Comment: Thanks, fmt is great for UTF-8 console output, but what about UTF-8 console input?

Comment: There is scnlib (https://github.com/eliaskosunen/scnlib) but for this particular case getline should be OK.

Comment: Standard C and C++ input **from the console** didn't work with UTF-8 for a long time for me. It always worked just fine when the source is a regular file. Not sure what is the exact status now. It seems to work when an "experimental" UTF-8 support is enabled in language settings, but it wasn't the case a few Windows updates ago.

Comment: While enabling UTF-8 in language settings is a good idea in general it is not needed for std::print and {fmt}. They work by using native Unicode API.

Comment: Output to the console is also not a big problem. Input is.

Comment: On Windows output is a big problem because of legacy code pages. Few languages do it right.

Comment: You do need to change the code page to 65001 to have native UTF-8 output (without using wide API). But it doesn't (didn't) help with the input.